# Django change password

Tags: html, django

Trying to change password using PasswordChangeView, but cannot get it working.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('profiles/settings/', update_profile, name='update_profile'),
    path('profiles/settings/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='accounts/settings.html'), 
        name='password_change'),
]
```

And i am trying to get the input fields correct in my html

```
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="password">
                <form id="id_password_change_form" method="POST" class="form-signin">{% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-3">Current Password</label>
                    <div class="col">
                      <input 
                      type="password" 
                      placeholder="Enter your current password" 
                      name="old_password" 
                      class="form-control" 
                      id="id_old_password" 
                      required="true" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-3">New Password</label>
                    <div class="col">
                      <input 
                      type="password" 
                      placeholder="Enter a new password" 
                      name="new_password1" 
                      class="form-control" 
                      id="id_new_password1" 
                      required="true" />
                      <small>Password must be at least 8 characters long</small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-3">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div class="col">
                      <input 
                      type="password" 
                      placeholder="Confirm your new password" 
                      name="new_password2" 
                      class="form-control" 
                      id="id_new_password2" 
                      required="true" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {% for field in form %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                      <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endfor %}
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

There is no error, and it do not update the password as supposed to. according to PasswordChangeView, I should not need to alter anything.

Comment: Did you check `{{ form.errors }}` or `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` ?

Comment: It is not giving any form errors, it updates the page as it should, but not changing the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem because of the wrong URLs definition, take a look at you `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('profiles/settings/', update_profile, name='update_profile'),
    path('profiles/settings/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='accounts/settings.html'), 
        name='password_change'),
]
```

You always hit `update_profile` view instead of `PasswordChangeView`. I think this is typo.

Comment: I have both on same template, they are separate with tabs using javascript, so because of that i thought i had to have same name due to same template?

Comment: You have the same template but different business logic in view. You have to create different users to update profiles and change password. You can have the same template but you should set `<form action=url` to correct view.

Comment: Completly lost here, but tried changing it to action="password_change" since the url name is that, but that did not work

Comment: But did you change also `path('profiles/settings/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView` to `path('profiles/password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView`? And action in form should be `{% url 'password_change' %}`

Comment: That worked, thank you. However now it says; Reverse for 'password_change_done' not found. I have to self redirect me to index html, what am i missing now

Comment: You have to pass success_url="/profiles/settings" into PasswordChangeView.as_view

Comment: Upvote my answer :)